# Proof of unique fixed point of an affine mapping under transformation conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

If given the following affine maps, how do I go about proving the existence of a unique fixed point, if and only if $(\lambda + \mu) \cos( \theta) \ne 1+ \lambda \mu$?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \lambda \cos \theta & -\lambda \sin \theta \\
        \mu \sin \theta & \mu \cos \theta \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
        b_1 \\
        b_2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

I recall a fixed point being present if there exists an $a_0$ such that $f(a_0) = a_0$, and that $b=0$ only at the fixed point. I am having issues tying this knowledge together, and I have not yet touched on the concept of unique fixed points in my computer graphics course.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mane by $b=0$ above.

Comment: The translation component,$b$ is only allowed to by equal to 0 at the fixed point if I am recalling correctly from linear algebra. It means the $b_1$ and $b_2$ can be eliminated from the equations, I think.

Comment: Well, under the above conditions you will have $x=0$ **iff** $b = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at it as a system $x = Ax +b$, or $(A-I)x = -b$. Then this system has
a **unique** solution **iff** $\det (A-I) \neq 0$. If you compute $\det (A-I)$ you
will get the equation above.

Comment: Ah, so it's just simple algebra then? Thank you!